# Why does setting a property to nil causes an array to be overlapped with data

Tags: ios, properties, null

I have an array that gets populated, initially with 26 objects.  This happens whenever the view appears.  When setting a new filter in another view, the core data fetch results in 6 objects, but when these are placed in the same property as before, I get 32 objects (26 + 6).

I had tried setting the self.property = nil; in the viewWillDisappear, but that results in the newly fetched 6 objects not being able to be inserted into the array anymore.

What should I do so that the property array is "cleaned out"?

Comment: Sounds like the number of objects you're pulling out of Core Data isn't what you're expecting it to be.

Comment: Yes they are...its exactly what they should be.  The problem is that the same array was getting filled in.  So originally I got 6 objects but when i fetched 26 new ones later, the original 6 were still there.  I solved it by niling the array and then recreating it.

Answer (score 2):

I'm assuming your using a NSMutableArray and not a NSArray. You just call `removeAllObjects` to empty the array. Setting it to nil deletes the array.

```
[self.property removeAllObjects];
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem.  It turns out my arrays were being filled with data and then refilled with more data later.  So I had to nil out the data in viewDidDisappear and then move my array creation code to viewWillAppear.

Voila!